# How can I create a new instance of explorer.exe by Microsoft Visual C++?

Tags: windows-explorer

When I use CreateProcess API, the result is successful, but there is no new instance of explorer.exe, and the old instance just open a folder.

So, How can I create a new instance of explorer.exe by Microsoft Visual C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Check  [Explorer.exe Command-Line Options for Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853) out.

Quote:

`The options that you can use with Explorer.exe are /n, /e, /root (plus an object), and /select (plus an object).
   Option            Function`

---

/n                Opens a new single-pane window for the default
                     selection. This is usually the root of the drive that
                     Windows is installed on. If the window is already
                     open, a duplicate opens.

/e                Opens Windows Explorer in its default view.

/root,    Opens a window view of the specified object.

/select,  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file,
                     or program selected.

Examples

---

Example 1: Explorer /select,C:\TestDir\TestProg.exe
              Opens a window view with TestProg selected.

Example 2: Explorer /e,/root,C:\TestDir\TestProg.exe
              Opens Explorer with drive C expanded and TestProg selected.

Example 3: Explorer /root,\TestSvr\TestShare
              Opens a window view of the specified share.

Example 4: Explorer /root,\TestSvr\TestShare,select,TestProg.exe
              Opens a window view of the specified share with TestProg selected.

Comment: I use /n parameter, but it dosen't work? There is still just only one instance of explorer.exe

Comment: @androitadroit2006 How do you call CreateProcess, can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

[Process.Start method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(VS.71).aspx)